# What is Squawk on radar tracking websites?

Tags: aircraft-operations, flightradar24

I have been noticing squawk on virtual radar, anyone have any idea what this is?

Comment: A picture or example of the site/area you are seeing this on would help greatly... Are you sure it isn't "squawk"?

Comment: https://staging.spee.ch/f9182d8ad3aa21c44f9bc312f3cd7a1247339111/Screenshot20181018-141536.jpg

Comment: The 4th column from the left in the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will go and have a read up on that now but it looks to be what I was after.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_traffic_control_radar_beacon_system